# LVO Operation Airbus 320

Tags: commercial-aviation

Let's say we are Cat 2 rated and shooting an approach with cat 2 weather condition. During the approach around (2000ft) , aircraft downgraded to Cat 1 single. can we continue the approach ?

Comment: I am struggling to understand the meaning of "downgraded" and "single" in this question.  Did you lose an engine, or did you lose a pilot?  Could you please expand your question just a bit, to be more user-friendly to those of us less steeped in airline-pilot lingo?  Thanks.  PS and that might include spelling out in actual words, what is the meaning of "LVO".  Is the "O" redundant with "Operation"?

Comment: so sorry :)...CAT1Single is what displyed on airbus 320 PFD when we armed approach. and my question is just what happens when aircraft had some internal failure that renders aircraft to downgraded to CAT1 Single on PFD. thank you @quietflyer

Comment: In what country is this flight taking place?

Comment: in one of UK destination @757toga

Comment: Is it a U.S. Air Carrier?

Comment: yes it is an US air carrier

Comment: (LVO = low visibility operations.). Do your company procedures prohibit you from continuing to cat I mins?  Do you have the vis for a cat I?  Because that would be the obvious best choice, right?

Comment: Your FCOM and/or Operations Specs should provide a clear answer to your question.  Very common circumstance that is typically addressed in company procedures and covered in training.

Comment: Just a side note: cat 1 single never shows up; dual or single only shows up in cat 3 to signal fail operational or fail passive capability; cat 1 or cat 2 show up with no single/dual indication.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking in a Commercial Air Transport context, we have 2 issues here: one regulatory and one procedural.

The procedural one: you can only continue an approach below 1000ft AAL in IMC if the approach is stabilised; that means, among other things, that all checklists have been completed. So if you have a failure most likely there will be a checklist to do and in case of a landing capability downgrade, a briefing to update. You need to have all of these done by 1000ft AAL to continue.

The regulatory one: according to EASA OPS regulations (European carriers) you may only continue an approach beyond a certain point, which is 1000ft above aerodrome level for a precision approach, if the reported RVR is at or above your landing capability (being the most restrictive of crew, airport and aircraft/company). This policy is called "commencement and continuation of approach" in the legislation (see CAT.OP.MPA.305 below).

https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/easy-access-rules/online-publications/easy-access-rules-air-operations?page=37#_DxCrossRefBm136404587

In FAA regulations (USA) the main difference here is that the entry into the final approach segment is used instead of 1000ftAAL for the regulatory aspect.

So in this case, what you usually do is start slowing down to final approach speed (to gain some time), continue the approach and ask for updated RVR information from TWR to see if before 1000ft AAL you can get an answer which allows you to proceed to the DA/H, and then assess whether or not you have visual references to land.

Obviously you can always opt to go around immediately, enter a hold, and decide what to do, and in case of doubt it is the safest option.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

FCOM and SOP (part B) would have precise answer to this. If weather CAT II and your DA becomes CAT I you go around.
[image: A320 PartB(SOP)]

Answer (score 0):

There 2 different concepts about the issue that you asked for.
1-Downgrading
2-Single Channel

1-Downgrading is the stepping back from fail operational to fail passive. AFS permits dual A/P engagement and reflects CAT III dual on FMA. System itself is said to be fail-operational if downgrading occurs, autoland capability is still. Why downgrading occurs ? Terrain, GPS, system malfunction...
On the other hand, if the fail passive system faces a problem, it can no longer be able to provide autoland. Both of these situations are not A/P failure.
2-Dropping to single channel; you face an A/P failure and not be able to engage 2 A/P at the same time.

Result,
If you downgrade from CAT III to CAT II ( on FMA ) and system is fail-operational (fleet,A/C info) you are able to continue approach with an extra caution.
If you have an A/P failure and operating with a single one, your minima becomes CATI minima. For this occasion you need to execute go around.
Infos I mentioned here are too shallow, please read more on FCOM,SOP.
Safe flights.